# Finding the span of 3 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, span

Let $V = \mathbb R^3$, a vector space over the reals. Find the span $W$ of
$\{(1, 2, 1), (3, −1, −4), (0, 7, 7)\}$
in the form $\{(x, y, z) ∈ V \mid ax + by + cz = 0\}$ for some $a, b, c$. Find a basis
for $W$.

I'm just really having trouble here; I know the definition of span, but not how to apply it here. And to write in a particular form and find a basis is confusing.

Comment: What are the steps you have learned to check whether or not you have a basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if the vectors are linearly independent. You can do this by putting the matrix
$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
1&2&1\\
3&-1&-4\\
0&7&7
\end{matrix}
\right]$$
into reduced row echelon form. This gives you
$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
1&0&-1\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&0
\end{matrix}
\right]$$
So the three vectors are not linearly independent, and any two vectors will be sufficient to find the span, which is a plane. I will use the vectors $(1,2,1)$ and $(3,-1,-4)$, which are linearly independent and form the basis you require. The cross product of these is $(-7,7,-7)$, giving you the normal vector of your plane. Therefore your span will be
$$\{(x, y, z) ∈ V | -7x + 7y + -7z = 0\}$$

Comment: Why wouldn't you choose $\{(1,0,-1),(0,1,1)\}$ as the basis instead after going to all the trouble of finding these vectors? It seems much easier to work with than the basis you chose. It gives the equation of the plane as $x-y+z=0$ directly, without having to divide through by $-7$ after taking the cross product.

Comment: Those were the vectors given by the OP, so I chose them to illustrate the intuition behind the span and basis. I was just using the matrix to check for linear independence. I noticed that the other answer posted regarded the vectors as column vectors, so the method I outlined would work in that case as well. BTW I used a calculator so it wasn't that much trouble.

Comment: Thank you; this was very helpful. We haven't actually learned to use matrices yet, but I think it was meant for us to show that the 3 vectors are L.D, but 2 of them are L.I (can be shown obviously by signs). Then the cross product made sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Write the condition(s) for matrix $\;A=\begin{bmatrix}1&3&0\\2&-1&7\\1&-4&7\end{bmatrix}$ and the augmented matrix
$$B=[A|X],\quad X=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix},$$
to have the same rank.